# React equivalent of jquery DOM access

Tags: jquery, reactjs, momentjs, materialize, pickadate

What is the equivalent of the following code:

```
           pick_attribute = moment(`2017-${month}-${day}`).format('x');
           // toggle colors
           color = day.hours <=3 ? 'orange' : color
           color = day.hours >3 ? 'green' : color
          //inject number of hours worked into calender view 
            $(`div[data-pick='${pick_attribute}']`).
            append(`<small class='${color}-text'>${day.hours}h</small>`);
           });
```

I am using pickadate.js and trying to add some styles based on a timesheet API. So if XX hours worked, I can add that as colored text in each of the corresponding date.
My `pick_attribute` is calculated from moments Unix Timstamp which is accurate and is able to get the element with that data attribute, so no problem there.

This code works as expected when I open the calendar but only the first `open` and other times it reverts. If I change the month frequently back and forth, I can see some of the changes in other months.

I am assuming is a is the virtual DOM and DOM not being insync but IDK. I am using the pickadate calender within materializeCSS The data-pick attribute is provided by the library and is unique(UNIX Timestamp).
Any thoughts on how I can do the same in react so I can try this differently? Thanks